# Selenium nested query to find top parent and then a child under that

Tags: dom, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, parent

I came across a scenario in selenium as given below:

Find a `<span>` contains text `span-text` and find it's parent node (not the immediate parent but the parent after traversing all levels up the DOM tree) with class `parent-class` and under that parent node find a `<img>` node with class `img-class`

Sample:

```
<div>             -(1)  
   <div>          -(2)
      <div>       -(3)
         <span>   -(4)  
            <div> -(5)
   <img>          -(6)
```

The way I am looking at it is - find (4) first then find its first ancestor (1) and then find (6) which actually comes under (2). I would prefer a nested query even if it looks complex.

Any help?

Comment: Meanwhile, I am gonna take a  look at xpath axes!

Comment: Is `span-text` some sample text or is that a real thing? When you say `SPAN` contains `span-text` does that mean the `innerText` or some attribute of that element? Can you put more of these details in the sample HTML above?

Comment: You can do that using `List<WebElement> imgs = $("span:contains('span-text')").closest(".parent-class").find("img.img-class").get();` and [seleniumQuery](https://github.com/seleniumQuery/seleniumQuery). (disclaimer: I'm the author.)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. I'm assuming for now that the `span-text` is `innerText` and not some attribute. If it's an attribute, this will probably get a lot simpler.

Basically we grab all the `DIV`s with a class of `parent-class` and loop through them looking for a child `SPAN` that has an innerText of `span-text`. Once we find it, we know we have the right parent so we find the child `IMG` with class `img-class'. I added the line to write out the found tag so that you can quickly verify that it's the right one.

```
List<WebElement> parents = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.parent-class"));
for (WebElement parent : parents)
{
    List<WebElement> spans = parent.findElements(By.tagName("span"));
    for (WebElement span : spans)
    {
        if (span.getText().contains("span-text"))
        {
            WebElement found = parent.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.img-class"));
            System.out.println(found.getAttribute("outerHTML")); // write out the element to the console to verify
        }
    }
}
```